# Кому в державу тесны миры

Tags: смысл, поэзия

В оде Гавриила Романовича Державина "На смерть князя Мещерского" есть такие строки, в которых говорится о Смерти:

*Глядит на всех — и на*  *царей,*

**Кому в державу тесны миры**;

*Глядит на пышных богачей*,

*Что в злате и сребре кумиры*;

*Глядит на прелесть и красы*,

*Глядит на разум возвышенный*,

*Глядит на силы дерзновенны*

*И точит лезвие косы*.

Выделенное мною выражение, возможно, интуитивно понятно (цари, которым мало целой планеты), но вот буквальный смысл его затенён. Как именно его надо толковать? Также хотелось бы уточнить значение следующего выражения: *...богачей, что в злате и сребре кумиры*. Имеется в виду, что они, обвешанные побрякушками, кумиры для других или что злато и сребро суть кумиры самих богачей?

Answer (score 1):

А что тут не ясного?

Держава и скипетр - символы власти монарха, держава - шар, на котором иногда изображались значимые для государства объекты, битвы и т. п.

Вот в эту-то державу и "были тесны" (т.е. не помещались) миры.
(+)
Вот второго вопроса не понял. Кумир - истукан, языческий символ поклонения. Часто были из драгоценных металлов. Что здесь не так?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, тут речь идёт о выдающихся царях и богачах. В первом случае логично предположить, что величие проявляется в таком огромном размере державы, что ей тесно в "мирах", однако говорится прямо обратное. Видимо, имеется в виду, что владения и победы царя так велики, что не помещаются на державе? Действительно, довольно просто, я сразу не понял. А вот с богачами всё же неясно: зачем упоминаются кумиры? Намёк на преклонение толпы, популярность, которые всё равно не спасут от смерти?

Comment: Спрашиваю по той причине, что у Державина иногда проскакивают причудливые речевые конструкции, непонятные современному читателю, например **быть себя он вечным чает**. Я подумал, что тут тоже может быть нечто эдакое.